# Tensor operator on nucleon nucleon interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum

> i'm trying to prove that from
> $$
> S_{12}=\left[3 \frac{\left(\vec{\sigma_{1}} \cdot \vec{r}\right)\left(\vec{\sigma_{2}} \cdot \vec{r}\right)}{r^{2}}-\vec{\sigma_{1}} \cdot \vec{\sigma_{2}}\right]
> $$
> then
> $$
> S_{12}=2\left[3 \frac{(\widehat{\vec{s}} \cdot \vec{r})^{2}}{r^{2}}-\widehat{\vec{s}}^{2}\right].
> $$
> Is true, given that $$\widehat{\vec{s}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{1}+\sigma_{2}\right)~?$$

Now i've found that from evaluating $(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r})^2$ that
$$(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r})^2= \frac{1}{2} \left( \vec{r}^2 +  (\vec{\sigma_1}\cdot \vec{r}) (\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot \vec{r})\right) \\
2(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r})^2  - \vec{r^2} = (\vec{\sigma_1}\cdot \vec{r}) (\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot \vec{r})$$

However when i tried to evaluate    $\vec{S}^2$ i've found that
$$
 \vec{S} = \frac{1}{2} (\vec{\sigma_1} + \vec{\sigma_2}) \\
 \vec{S}^2  = \frac{1}{4} (\vec{\sigma_1}+\vec{\sigma_2})^2 \\
 =\frac{1}{4} (\vec{\sigma_1}^2 + \vec{\sigma_2}^2 + \underbrace{(\vec{\sigma_1} \vec{\sigma_2}) +( \vec{\sigma_2}  \vec{\sigma_1})}_{\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2\}= 0}) \\
 = \frac{1}{4} (2 I) \\
 = \frac{1}{2} I
$$

which i don't think is true? But i'm having a hard time figuring out what i did wrong

Comment: Those two operators don't anti-commute.  They *commute*, because they are operators corresponding to different degrees of freedom; in this case, they are the spins of two different particles.  Operators corresponding to different particles commute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the spin operators don't anti-commute.  The spin operators, being operators corresponding to different particles, *commute*. You're getting this mixed up with the fact that the Pauli spin matrices of a *single* particle anti-commute (provided they are *different* spin matrices). But that's not what's going on here.  Instead, this the dot product between the full spin *vectors* of two *different* particles.  (Really, under the hood, we are taking the tensor product of the two operators, one for particle 1 and one for particle 2.)

Thus, when you compute $\hat{S}^2$, you should actually get
$$
\hat{S}^2
=
\frac{1}{4}
\left(
\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1
+
\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2
+2\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2
\right)
=
\frac{1}{4}
\left(
3\hat{I}+3\hat{I}
+2\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2
\right)
=\frac{3}{2}\hat{I}+\frac{1}{2}\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2\,.
$$
Note that $\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_i\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_i = 3\hat{I}$ because the dot product actually yields the sum of the three squares of the *components* of the spin vector, each of which is a Pauli spin matrix whose square is the identity.

Combined with the first term, which you've computed correctly as
$$
\frac{1}{r^2}(\vec{\textbf{S}}\cdot\textbf{r})^2
=
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{r^2}
\left(
r^2\hat{I} - (\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\textbf{r})
(\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2\cdot\textbf{r})
\right)\,,
$$
we get
\begin{align}
2\left(
3\frac{1}{r^2}(\hat{\textbf{S}}\cdot\textbf{r})^2
-\hat{{S}}^2
\right)
&=2
\left(
3
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{r^2}
\left(
r^2\hat{I} - (\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\textbf{r})
(\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2\cdot\textbf{r})
\right)
-\left(
\frac{3}{2}\hat{I}+\frac{1}{2}\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2
\right)
\right)
\\
&=3
\frac{(\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\textbf{r})
(\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2\cdot\textbf{r})
}
{r^2}
-\frac{1}{2}\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_1\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_2
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'm having a really hard time understanding all of this and your explanation helps a lot. Again, thank you.